# How to sort by state regardless of previous code?

Tags: sql-server

"Give me a list of the Vendors we have used for any sort of design work and show all other vendors that are in the same state as them."

I am attempting to filter it where everyone in the state of CA should show up even if the category is not correct. There should be 75 and I am still only getting 3. I am using the not exists which I would assume would trigger it. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
  InvoiceLineItemDescription AS ITEMNAME,
  VendorState
FROM InvoiceLineItems
JOIN Invoices
  ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
JOIN Vendors
  ON invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
WHERE InvoiceLineItemDescription = 'cover design'
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT
  InvoiceLineItemDescription
FROM InvoiceLineItems ili
JOIN invoices i
  ON i.InvoiceID = ili.InvoiceID
JOIN Vendors v
  ON i.VendorID =
  v.VendorID
WHERE VendorState = 'Ca')





Invoices Table:
          VendorID | InvoiceNumber | InvoiceDate | InvoiceTotal | PaymentTotal | CreditTotal |
         TermsID | InvoiceDueDate | PaymentDate | ________________| ________________
            Vendors table VendorID | VendorName | VendorAdress1 | VendorAdress2 | VendorCity |
     VendorState | VendorZipCode | VendorPhone |__ VendorContactLName | VendorContactFName 
| DefaultTermsID | DefaultAccountNo | 

            InvoiceLineItems | InvoiceID | InvoiceSequence | AccountNO | InvoiceLineItemAmount |
         InvoiceLineItemDescription |
```

Comment: Please show your table layout you have here,

Comment: VendorID |
InvoiceNumber |
InvoiceDate |
InvoiceTotal |
PaymentTotal |
CreditTotal |
TermsID |
InvoiceDueDate |
PaymentDate |
________________|

________________
Vendors table

VendorID |
VendorName |
VendorAdress1 |
VendorAdress2 |
VendorCity |
VendorState |
VendorZipCode |
VendorPhone |__
VendorContactLName |
VendorContactFName |
DefaultTermsID |
DefaultAccountNo |

InvoiceLineItems |

InvoiceID |
InvoiceSequence |
AccountNO |
InvoiceLineItemAmount |
InvoiceLineItemDescription |

Comment: Please edit your question, format it a bit instead of placing it in an un-formatted comment.  Help us help you here.  Include the table the same as if you were doing a CREATE TABLE for each of the tables you have

Comment: Sorry about that, and thank you! Now it is 31 rows off, and it created a second section table where I want them all to be combined in the same table.